# Can I create my own Ubuntu 16.04 Live DVD / USB with patches?

Tags: 16.04, live-usb, live-cd

The only Ubuntu Live DVD I have is for version 14.04.1.

I recently upgraded to 16.04 when the semi-weekly updates nudged me to do so. After the upgrade I had to patch various parts of the system for my laptop to behave. I also upgraded to Kernel 4.6.3 and then to Kernel 4.7.1 and then 4.7.2 immediately after that.

Today I was thinking I should create a spare 16.04 Live DVD "just in case" but then started wondering if I could make one incorporating all the changes I've done the last few weeks.

So.... Can I? and how would I go about doing it?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1:**

To add clarity it's not a kernel patch or major rewrite. There are just a few files I want to **add**:

```
/etc/acpi/events/lid-open
/etc/acpi/events/lid-close
/etc/acpi/events/tv-sound
```

I need to add my cell phone to the usb id's and change terminal to colour prompt so two files need to be **changed**:

```
/usr/share/hwdata/usb.ids
~/.bashrc
```

Optionally I might want to setup plymouth themes for sunrise and sunset instead of Ubuntu logo with horizontal dots. Also within grub kernel command line "kaslr" option could be added.

Comment: What did you patch? If you patched the kernel, you could consider submitting it upstream.

Comment: @edwinksl Oh let me see... Um PulseAudio would switch TV sound over to laptop when going to sleep requiring manual resetting on resume, so I had to change some sleep.conf thing... It's documented somewhere... suspend wasn't working in Ubuntu settings or SystemD so I used ACPI-Events / actions with sleep thing wake up thing... that's written somewhere too... There was more... also written somewhere.  The kernel updates I installed were needed to slow down Intel CPU, reduce load, balance load evenly and lower temperature. I didn't patch the kernel so I should change the title?

Comment: The title looks fine to me but I would get rid of the kernel tag. If you were just changing dotfiles, you can look at https://dotfiles.github.io/.

Comment: Whoaa those dotfiles are over my head. I just wrote simple 3 line pm-sleep, pm-wake and pm-tvsound bash scripts. My pm-tvsound script was the hardest because it involved google searches where a link to an answer linked to an answer linked to a question with some incorrect parameters I had to figure out such as user id = 1001. Sorry I have to run out soon so this sounds a little sketchy without reviewing my librecalc notes.

Comment: @edwinksl thanks for nuking the kernel tag I was just about to do it based on your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

[Linux Respin](http://www.remastersys.org/) is a fork of the original [Remastersys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remastersys) , designed to do just that, remaster an ISO.
The deb file, unfortunately, has a dependency problem in 16.04 so you have to compile from the source [here](https://github.com/ch1x0r/LinuxRespin/tree/master/ubuntu/UbuntuSource-May2016).

Comment: Thank you very much. I was reading about LinuxRespin and Remastersys a few days ago for building your own Linux Distro but didn't think of it for my own needs today. I'll upvote your answer (I see you are an up & coming AskUbuntu star with many answers and comments over 24 hours) but I hope someone comes up with a simpler solution, ie expand this compressed archive, copy your files over top, compress the archive again, etc.